# Can I add additional fields to "State and Country Picklists"

Tags: custom-field, country-and-state

My org uses "State and Country Picklists" and I've been asked if it's possible add additional fields to the object so we can align each country to a region, sub-region and cluster and the ISO 3 digit country code.

For example: 
Madagascar = Country Code: 450, Region: CEMEA, Sub-Region: SSA, Cluster: East Africa... 
To do this, I would need to add 4 new fields to the "State and Country Picklists" so that I could assign each country the proper regional values.
Is it possible to add custom fields to the "State and Country Picklists"?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, hence the comment but the state and county picklist is not an object where you could add more fields to. So I think this is a no. It's just a global picklist.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot add more fields to the standard picklist.

You can add new complete country/state options, but you're limited to whatever fields they provide as options.

There's many ideas about exploring enhancements in this regard that you can look to upvote although I think it's important to highlight they don't seem to have this on their roadmap based on the info below:

1. [Accepting ISO 3 code values and compliant text updates](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000keCJAAY) might match what you're looking, but has no updates and is **6 years old**.
2. [State & Country Picklists as a custom field type](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxcNAAQ)
   for other custom object. No update for 2 years and is **6 years old**.
3. Similar to #1 above, except with more focus on [configuring accepted text values](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000keCOAAY). **6 years old**.
4. [Ability to customize the sort order](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l8LSAAY) is **5 years old** and no update.
5. Currently, you're not even able to use [deployments for new countries or states](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l6DGAAY). **5 years old**, no update.